# AWS Cognito identity pool GetID validation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

according to the AWS doc, the Cognito identity pool is making a validation for the GetID api call.
What is the purpose of this first validation ?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In some IDM system the validation with the login provider is to validate that the session is still valid.
so in case the session was revoked for some reason or admin action, cognito will return an error.